# not able to deserialize from xml file into an object in c# in.net 3.0 WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, deserialization

***i have following data contract class in WCF :***

```
[DataContract]
public class PropertyDetails
{
    # region >>---> private members

        string city;        
        string propertyType;       
        double price;        
        string propertyClass;  

    # endregion

    #region >>---> public properties
        [DataMember]
        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
            set { city = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string PropertyType
        {
            get { return propertyType; }
            set { propertyType = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public double Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string PropertyClass
        {
            get { return propertyClass; }
            set { propertyClass = value; }
        } 
    #endregion
}
```

}

***i am creating nodes in XML file using the following code :***

```
public void insertPropertyRecord(string city, string propertyType, double price, string propertyClass)
    {
        XmlTextReader propertyRecordReader = new XmlTextReader(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLPropertyRecords"]);
        XmlDocument xmlDocPropertyRecords = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocPropertyRecords.Load(propertyRecordReader);
        propertyRecordReader.Close();

        XmlElement xmlPropertyRecordRootNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.DocumentElement;
        if (!xmlPropertyRecordRootNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            XmlElement xmlPropertyRecordNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("propertyrecord");
            XmlElement xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = null;

                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("city");
                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = city;
                xmlPropertyRecordNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("propertytype");
                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = propertyType;
                xmlPropertyRecordNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("price");
                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(price);
                xmlPropertyRecordNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("propertyclass");
                xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = propertyClass;
                xmlPropertyRecordNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

            xmlPropertyRecordRootNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordNode);
        }
        else
        {
            XmlElement xmlPropertyRecordLastNode = (XmlElement)xmlPropertyRecordRootNode.LastChild;
            XmlElement xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = null;
                XmlElement xmlPropertyRecordNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("propertyrecord");

                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("city");
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = city;
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("propertytype");
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = propertyType;
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("price");
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(price);
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode = xmlDocPropertyRecords.CreateElement("propertyclass");
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.InnerText = propertyClass;
                    xmlPropertyRecordChildNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordChildNode);

            xmlPropertyRecordLastNode.AppendChild(xmlPropertyRecordNode);
        }
        xmlDocPropertyRecords.Save(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlPropertyRecords"]);
    }
```

***i am trying to get the nodes in object using deserialization using the following code :***

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<PropertyDetails>));
        TextReader sr = new StreamReader(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLPropertyRecords"]);
        List<PropertyDetails> obj = new List<PropertyDetails>();
        obj = (List<PropertyDetails>)ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

but i am getting an error in line for deserialization as invalid operation exception 
 the xml fie created is ike below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<propertydetails>
  <propertyrecord>
    <City>delhi</City>
    <PropertyType>residential</PropertyType>
    <Price>4500000</Price>
    <PropertyClass>flat</PropertyClass>
  </propertyrecord>
</propertydetails>
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems XML is not in good shape. Try to use XML as mentioned below.

```
<ArrayOfPropertydetails>
  <Propertydetails>
    <City>delhi</City>
    <PropertyType>residential</PropertyType>
    <Price>4500000</Price>
    <PropertyClass>flat</PropertyClass>
  </Propertydetails>
</ArrayOfPropertydetails>
```

Comment: Thanx shailesh it worked but i would be really grateful if you could explain the reason. how was it not in good shape.i mean XML can be described as we wish and tags were wel formed and closed so why does changing propertydetails to arrayofpropertydetails  worked?

Comment: Seems you are trying to serialize List<Propertydetails>. In this case XML must start with <ArrayOfPropertydetails>.

Answer (score 0):

Well Formed" XML document has correct XML syntax.

The syntax rules were described in the previous chapters:
 •XML documents must have a root element
•XML elements must have a closing tag
•XML tags are case sensitive
•XML elements must be properly nested
•XML attribute values must be quoted
     
     
      Tove
      Jani
      Reminder
      Don't forget me this weekend!